# Filtering custom model

Tags: model, filter

i have a custom model that i want to display in a page-anted grid for users on a page in storefront. i can call the collection in the phtml with a filter and it works, but when i move the call to the block it does not work if i try to filter (i can call the whole collection just when i add the filter it stops working)the collection any ideas? this is the call

```
Mage::getModel('model/name')->getCollection()->addFilter('group_id', $val);
```

Comment: Perhaps `$val` is undefined... can you share more of your code?

Comment: oh I am embarrassed `$val` wasn't set properly i was annoyed when i saw your comment but you were right thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use `addFieldToFilter` instead of `addFilter`:

```
Mage::getModel('model/name')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('group_id', $val);
```

Comment: oh I am embarrassed $val wasn't set properly oops, thank you anyhow

Comment: Generally a good comment, but it depends on the implementation of the custom collection